# @Named annotation not complete values

Tags: jsf, annotations, facelets, cdi

i have my xhtml page below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"> 
<h:head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Portal Financeiro </title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" />

</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="form">


        <h:inputText value="#{testeBean.name}" />

        <h:commandButton value="Enviar" action="#{testeBean.enviar}"  />

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Behind my bean:

```
package br.com.teste.controller;

import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TesteBean {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void enviar(){

    System.out.println("NAME " +  name );


}

}
```

The problem is: When i submit the form the value of the field name returns null.

My configuration:

- I have the file beans.xml inside WEB-INF
- I'm working with Jboss 7.1.0 or Glassfish 4.0 whatever  gives the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bad import, CDI annotations are in `javax.enteprise.context` package. Thus you should import `javax.enteprise.context.RequestScoped`. Or for this particular combination (`@RequestScoped` + `@Named`) you can use built-it [stereotype](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhqc.html) called `@Model`.

Comment: A simple way to avoid this problem is to learn the correct package name (duh) but for RequestScoped and Named you can also use @Model.